# Перегревается macbook в инструментах разработчика

Tags: macbook

Macbook pro 13 2017 практически новый. Macos 10.14.4
Подключен к внешнему монитору 4к через переходник hdmi и отдельно зарядка.
Работаю с закрытой крышкой с внешними клавой и мышкой. 
При открытии исходного кода в инструментах разработчика Safari или Chrome греется до 95 град, потом включаются кулеры на полную 7200 и остывает до 80. В safari появляется предупреждение, что вкладка требует много энергии.
Это нормальная работа? Или что-то с ним не так? Работать не комфортно с постоянным писком кулеров. Только стоит перейти на другую вкладку без кода сразу остывает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: походу на той вкладке код который грузит комп. Это может быть рекурсия,бесконечный цикл и т.д.

Comment: Обнаружил еще один сайт http://limb.su http://joxi.ru/J2bkzjnS0XgZPA.jpg Проблемы все теже нагрев до 80 градусов и 7200 оборотов